# Controller setup with three models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have a three models: `Homework`, `Question`, and `HomeworkAttempt`.

`homework.rb`:

```
class Homework < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :questions
  has_many :homework_attempts
end
```

`question.rb`:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :homework
end
```

`homework_attempt.rb`:

```
class HomeworkAttempt < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :homework
  belongs_to :student
  has_many :answer_attempts
end
```

I setup two controllers, thinking this would be the best way. My homework controller is empty, and exists simply for nesting the `homework_attempt`. My homework attempts controller looks like this:

```
class HomeworkAttemptsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
    @homework = Homework.find(params[:homework_id])
    @questions = @homework.questions
    @homework_attempt = HomeworkAttempt.new
    current_user.homework_attempts << @homework_attempt
    @title = @homework.name
  end
  ...
end
```

I want to set it up so that the user can create a new homework attempt based on the homework. How should I go about doing this? What columns will I need in my model?

Thanks!

Comment: I only got `has one` `homework attempt` at school :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell exactly what you're asking, but I have some ideas that might help you get started:

In your relations, it seems like you're trying to use models that you never created. For example, `belongs_to :group` and `has_many :answer_attempts` both imply that those models exist, but you haven't mentioned them anywhere else. If you want to use these relations, you must create these models.

Also, it seems like you're doing too much work in your `new` action. The fourth line is usually all that's needed in such an action, but it is hard to tell without more detail on what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

You will need much more than you've shown here to make this all work. You really ought to have a controller to manage the CRUD for each of your models, unless you have some other plan that I'm not seeing. If you provide more information on what you currently have and what you're trying to get to, I can edit my answer to try to be more helpful.

Comment: I have groups; I was just trying to include relevant models. Answer attempts was from a long time ago, I think I got all this from an old git commit. I'm going to edit my question to fix it.

Comment: If your question is what database columns you'll need to make these relations work, every `belongs_to :blank` will require an integer `:blank_id` field in that model's database table. For example, `HomeworkAttempts` needs both a `:student_id` and a `:homework_id` field.

Comment: Right; I know that. My question is about controllers, which don't make as much sense to me - I'm unsure of what is considered 'most correct'.

Comment: Which part of the controller are you looking for clarification on? Assuming your routes and forms are set up to match, the above code seems like it should work, even if it isn't the most idiomatic.

Comment: Do I want to make a controller for each model? Or could I combine some... and it might not be idiomatic, but it fits some very very individual needs ;).

Comment: It really depends on how you want the application to flow. You don't need a controller for each model if you don't plan on manipulating them individually. Plan out how you want the data to be input and presented, then derive the necessary controller actions from that.